# Convert Array of Strings To Array of Objects using Lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is there an easy way in lodash to take this:

```
const sampleSource = [
  "String 1",
  "String 2",
]
```

And get this:

```
[
  {id: "String 1", text: "String 1"},
  {id: "String 2", text: "String 2"},
]
```

I need to format it like this to pass into a 3rd party react component. I've played with .map and .zipObject a bit but havent been able to get it right.

I thought something like this should work:

```
_.chain(sampleSource).map(s => ({ id: s, text: s })).value()
```

But it gives me:

```
[
  {
    id: ["String 1", "String 2"],
    text: ["String 1", "String 2"],
  }
]
```

Comment: The code you posted produces the correct result when I try it, not the result you show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.
Added chain example.

```js
const sampleSource = [
  "String 1",
  "String 2",
]

let result = _.map(sampleSource, function(item) {
  return {id: item, text: item};
});

console.log(result);

let result2 = _.chain(sampleSource).map(function(item) {
  return {id: item, text: item};
});

console.log(result2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Interesting, any idea why it doesn't work when chained?

Comment: Weird, I must have another problem then. Thanks for taking a look. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: It ended up being that my initial array was actually contained in an object. End of day brain lapse. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help. Glad you found your problem and were able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need lodash for this, ordinary JavaScript `.map()` should work.

```js
const sampleSource = [
  "String 1",
  "String 2",
];

const result = sampleSource.map(s => ({id: s, text: s}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: It has some extra handling for null values I like. Of course I could handle that case myself, but I like the elegance of a one liner. I'm going to have ~10 of these in a react compose container.

Comment: OK, then we're back to the fact that your code actually works. The problem must be with the extra handling that you haven't shown.

Answer (score -1):

There is a method in `lodash` named [keyBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#keyBy).

You can use it like this

```js
const sampleSource = [
  "String 1",
  "String 2",
];

const result = _.keyBy(sampleSource);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This doesn't return what the OP wants it to return.